# JSONAssert ignore order for specific field

Tags: java, jsonassert

There are two JSON strings to be compared by JSONAssert:

**StringA**

```
{
    "items": [
        "SfWn8eQ",
        "QiOiJrw",
        "2Npc2Nv"
    ],
    "auths": [
        "5895c0a1-0fa9-4222-bbfb-5f96f6737cd7",
        "415499a6-daa3-45b7-b967-83aa94a38da1",
        "5d572399-a2ae-4bc4-b989-e2115028612e"
    ]
}
```

**StringB**

```
{
    "items": [
        "SfWn8eQ",
        "QiOiJrw",
        "2Npc2Nv"
    ],
    "auths": [
        "415499a6-daa3-45b7-b967-83aa94a38da1",
        "5d572399-a2ae-4bc4-b989-e2115028612e",
        "5895c0a1-0fa9-4222-bbfb-5f96f6737cd7"
    ]
}
```

The two JSON strings are expected to be equal:

- Compare `items` in `STRICT` mode, i.e. "Strict checking. Not extensible, and strict array ordering."
- Compare `auths` in `NON_EXTENSIBLE` mode, i.e. "Non-extensible checking. Not extensible, and non-strict array ordering."

In other words, the comparison is order-sensitive for `items` but order-tolerant for `auths`.

The `JSONAssert` code is:

```
CustomComparator comparator = new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE,
        new Customization("auths",
                // A lenient comparison for auths. Compare ignoring the order.
                (o1, o2) -> (
                        TestUtil.equals(((List<String>)o1), ((List<String>)o2))
                )
        )
);


try {
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, actual, comparator);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Assert.fail();
}
```

The `TestUtil` code for comparing two String lists ignoring order is:

```
public class KmsAgentTestUtil {
    public static boolean equals(List<String> auths1, List<String> auths2) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(auths1) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(auths2)) {
            return true;
        }

        Collections.sort(auths1);
        Collections.sort(auths2);
        return auths1.equals(auths2);
    }
}
```

It gets error because it doesn't comply with `JSONAssert` convention, but I didn't find another solution yet. Someone help me out?

Comment: "It gets error" what is the error you get ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by ModelAssert - https://github.com/webcompere/model-assert, which allows comparison order to be relaxed on a per path basis. Example from the OP problem:

```java
assertJson(stringA)
    .where()
       .at("/auths").arrayInAnyOrder()
    .isEqualTo(stringB);
```